# Coldfusion Jquery Ajax data format

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

```
$.ajax({
type: 'Get',
url: '/services/user.cfc?method=GetCompanyJson',
data: 'Companyid=' + ui.item.id,
datatype: 'json',
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// show error
alert(errorThrown)},
success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
alert(response);
$('#Company_Name').val(response.name);                  
}
});
```

The cffunction is;

```
<cffunction name="GetCompanyJson" access="remote" returntype="struct"     returnformat="json" output="false">
        <cfargument name="Companyid" required="true" />
        <cfquery name="QComp" datasource="#request.dsn_live#">
        select id,name,address_line_1,address_line_2,city,state,zip,phone
        from companies
        where id = #val(arguments.Companyid)#
    </cfquery>
    <cfset var comp = structNew() />
    <cfset comp["ID"] = '#qcomp.ID#' />
    <cfset comp["name"] = '#qcomp.name#' />
    <cfset comp["address_line_1"] = '#Qcomp.address_line_1#' />
    <cfset comp["address_line_2"] = '#Qcomp.address_line_2#'/>
    <cfset comp["city"] = '#Qcomp.city#' />
    <cfset comp["state"] = '#Qcomp.state#' />
    <cfset comp["zip"] = '#Qcomp.zip#' />
    <cfset comp["phone"] = '#Qcomp.phone#' />
        <cfreturn comp>
    </cffunction>
```

The returned data is;

```
"{"phone":"8634500","state":"CA","zip":"92618","name":"Taco Bell Corp","ID":"2200","city":"Irvine","address_line_2":"","address_line_1":"1 Glen Bell Way"}"
```

How do I access this data in Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(response.phone);
    console.log(response.state);
}
```

Comment: response.phone gives me "undefined"

Comment: `datatype` should be `dataType`

Comment: That made a big defference, but;
Object {phone: "8634500", state: "CA", zip: "92618", name: "Taco Bell Corp", ID: "2200"…}

is what I get now. Address 1 is stuffed into the value in;

$('#company_address1').val(response.address_line_1);

But the name doesn't show up using:

$('#Company_Name').val(response.name);

Comment: Are you certain the id is 'Company_Name'? JavaScript is case sensitive, and since your other field example is all lower case, that may be your issue.

Comment: That was a good catch.  But the following is how I get the data to the screen;

  $('#company_name').val(response.name);
  $('#company_address1').val(response.address_line_1);
  $('#company_address2').val(response.address_line_2);
  $('#Company_City').val(response.city);
  $('#company_State').val(response.state);
  $('#company_zip').val(response.zip);
  $('#company_phone').val(response.phone);

But the name, city, and state elements are not filled in.

Comment: so, if you console.log those missing values, do they show there? Also, if you use fiddler or chrome dev tools, do all the values show, with the right names/cases? in chrome dev tools at lease, you can also console.log(response) and get the whole object dumped

Comment: Yes, console.log shows all of the variables. And I am using the same variable names that I do in the Jquery statement to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your reformatted to plain
Like this

```
<cffunction name="GetCompanyJson" access="remote" returntype="struct"     returnformat="plain">
```

Now you can access it into your Ajax success request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery.parseJSON() on your response object like this:

```
success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var RespObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(RespObj.phone);
    console.log(RespObj.state);
}
```

I think this should work. You could also replace your .ajax() call with a .getJSON() and that will return the parsed object.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/